# My c program keeps crashing and I do not know why

Tags: arrays, c

I am writing a program like hangman in c and I am trying to run it .The problem is that it's working fine until I give it a letter to quess the word but then it crashes with -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Can someone help me solve this, I think its something really small that I cant
see  .  Thank you for helping me!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Rules(void);
void maskWord (char starword[], int size);
int playRound(char starword[], char answer[]);
void updateStarWord(char starword[], char answer[], char userguess);
int occurancesInWord(char userguess, char answer[]);

int c=0;
char answer[128];
int N;

int main()
{
    int ch,size;
    char starword[1000];
    do
    {
        printf("---Welcome to Hangman!---\n");
        printf("1.Start Game\n2.Instructions\n3.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(ch>0&& ch<4)
        {
            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    maskWord(starword,size);break;
                case 2:
                    Rules();break;
            }
        }
        else
            system("cls");
    }
    while(ch!=3);
    return 0;
}

void Rules(void)
{
    do
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nThe word to guess is represented by a row of dashes representing each letter of the word.");
            printf("\nRules may permit or forbid proper nouns, such as names, places, brands, or slang.");
            printf("\nIf the guessing player suggests a letter which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions.");
            printf("\nIf the suggested letter does not occur in the word, the other player draws one element of a hanged stick figure as a tally mark.\n");
        }
        while(getchar()!='\n');
    }
    while(getchar()!='\n');
}

void maskWord (char starword[], int size)
{
    printf("Enter word to guess: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf(" %s", answer);
    int N = strlen(answer);
    int mask[N];
    for (int i=0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        mask[i] = 0;
    }
    playRound(mask,N);
}

int playRound(char starword[], char answer[])
{
    // Loop over each round of guessing
    int gameover = 0;
    while (! gameover)
    {
        // Print word with *s for unguessed letters
        printf("The word is : ");
        for(int j=0; j < answer; ++j)
        {
            if (starword[j])
            {
                printf("%c", answer[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("*");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        // Get player's next guess
        char guess;
        printf("\nGive a letter: ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf(" %c", &guess);
        updateStarWord(starword,answer,guess);
    }

}

void updateStarWord(char starword[], char answer[], char userguess)
{
    // Mark true all mask positions corresponding to guess
    int k;
    for(k=0; k < answer; ++k)
    {
        if ((answer[k]) ==(userguess))
        {
            starword[k] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to add temporary printf statements to narrow down where the crash happens and then tell us what line it is happening on.  Also, please tell us the exact keystrokes you are inputting into this game to make it crash.

Comment: @DavidGrayson it crashes in the updateStarWord function in the if statement. no matter what letter I input the same crash.

Comment: [How much research/effort is expected of SO users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What is this?   for(k=0; k < answer; ++k)

Comment: sprinkle your code with `fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: reached line %d.\n", __LINE__);`

Comment: Note that using a good (high) warning level on your compiler will make issues like this much easier to spot. Among many other warnings, I get a very clear *"warning: comparison between pointer and integer"* with my compiler. Judging by `system("cls");`, I'm guessing you are using MSVC, in which case  you should try using a [compiler warning option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-170): `/W4` or `/Wall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop doesn't make sense because the condition for terminating it is `k < answer`.  You are comparing an integer (`k`) to a pointer (`answer`).  The compiler should have warned you about this, so make sure your compiler warnings are turned on and you are paying attention to them.  Pointers and integers are different things, and comparing them is almost never what you want to do.

If `answer` is null-terminated, you could probably replace that condition with `answer[k]`.  Or maybe `updateStarWord` needs to take an argument that indicates the length of `answer`, and then the condition would be `k < answer_length`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I am using sizeof to get it but still not working.

Comment: OK, just try replacing `k < answer` with `k < strlen(answer)` and see if that works.

Comment: Using `sizeof` on a pointer is a very common mistake... it just gives you the size of the pointer, which is typically 4 or 8 bytes.  Note that `sizeof` is always evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Fixed it, I messed up what I was sending in the answer[] from the start, thank you for the help!

Comment: Presumably, `playRound(mask,N);`? Make sure you turn your compiler warnings way up - there are more issues with this code.